# Convergence of expected values and integrability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm trying to prove a result for a homework assignment, and I got to a point that if the following result is true, then the result follows.

> Let $X_n$ be a sequence of positive random variables and $X$ be a positive random variable. Does $$E(X_n) \rightarrow E(X)$$ imply that $$|X_n - X| \in L^1$$ (i.e. $E(|X_n - X|) < \infty$).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think convergence in the mean is sufficient. However, if $E(X_n^2),E(X^2)<\infty$ then I think you can say that, based on the below bounds:

$|E[X_n-X]|\leq E[|X_n-X|[ \leq E[(X_n-X)^2] = E[X_n^2]-2E[X_nX]+E[X^2]$

Since $E[X_nX]=Cov[X_n,X]+E[X_n]E[X]$ we can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $(i.e, |COV[X,Y]| \leq \sigma_X\sigma_y)$ to make the bound $E[X_n]E[X]-\sigma_{X_n}\sigma_X\leq E[X_nX]\leq E[X_n]E[X]+\sigma_{X_n}\sigma_X$

Putting all this together and taking the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$, we get:

$0\leq E|X_n-X| \leq E[X_n^2]+E[X^2]-2\{[E[X]]^2-\sigma_X\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sigma_{X_n}\}$

Therefore, if the second moments of X and the sequence $X_n$ are finite then $|X_n-X| \in \mathcal{L^1}$ Note that the above is merely a sufficient condition, so if it is false, it doesn't imply $E[|X_n-X|]=\infty$.

Hope that helps.